# Is type the super class of all classes in Python?

Tags: python, superclass

Given that `type` is the superclass of all classes, why `isinstance(1, type)` is  `False`?
Am I understanding the concept wrong?

Answer (score 13):

`type` isn't the superclass of all classes.  It is the type of all classes (that don't have a custom metaclass).  Note the difference:

```
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> isinstance(1, type)
False
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True
```

The number 1 is not an instance of type.  Rather, the `int` type itself is an instance of `type`.

Edit:

These examples may help you:

```
>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>> issubclass(1, int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    issubclass(1, int)
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> isinstance(Foo, type)
True
>>> issubclass(Foo, type)
False # Note the difference from the previous!
>>> isinstance(Foo, object)
True
>>> issubclass(Foo, object)
True
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True
>>> issubclass(int, type)
False # Note the difference from the previous!
```

From your comment, it seems you are misunderstanding how inheritance works.  There is a difference between being an instance of a type and being a subclass (or subtype) of a type.  If an object X is an *instance* of type A, and type A is a *subclass* of type B, then X is also an instance of B.  But if type A is an *instance* of type B, then X is not an instance of B.  In other words, subclasshood is transitive, but instancehood is not.

A real world analogy would be between something like "species" and "homo sapiens".  You could say that "species" is a type and "homo sapiens" is an instance of that type; in other words, "homo sapiens" is a particular species.  But "homo sapiens" is also a type, and an individual human is an instance of that type.  For instance, Barack Obama (to pick a well-known example) is an instance of "homo sapiens"; that is, he is a particular homo sapiens.  But Barack Obama is not an instance of species; he is not a species himself.

The relationship between `type`, `int`, and the number 1 is similar.  The number 1 is an instance of `int`, and `int` is an instance of `type`, but that doesn't mean that 1 is an instance of type.

Comment: what i mean is when you type  isinstance(1,int) gives true and when you type isinstance(int,type) it also gives true..it means int is an instance of type and 1 is an instance of int.right?.thats why i asked the question. It still confuses me.:(

Comment: @bibeesh: See my edited answer.  Hopefully that helps clear it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.It helped me a lot.I forgot the basic rule that everything is inherited from object itself.

Comment: @Brenbran: I think this answer misses explaining more directly what type actually is: the metaclass of most built-in types. And "object" is the superclass of most built-in types asked by the O.P.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `type` is not the supertype of all builtin types. `object` is.